# one-relator groups which are free-by-cyclic

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, geometric-group-theory, semidirect-product, combinatorial-group-theory

I am reading an article of Baumslag:

Baumslag, Gilbert, "Finitely generated cyclic extensions of free groups are residually finite." Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 5 (1971), 87–94.

and he mentions that many one-relator groups, in particular, fundamental groups of surfaces, are free-by-cyclic, see picture. Could somebody comment on this: how are surface groups free-by-cyclic? Or the one-relator groups mentioned by Baumslag?

[image]

Comment: Note that each infinite index subgroup of a surface group is free.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Will it be finitely generated?

Comment: No, never, unless it is a trivial group. But did Baumslag make this assumption?

Comment: Baumslag does not make this assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orientable surface group is free-by-cyclic: if the standard generators are $x_1,...,x_g, y_1,...,y_g$ then the homomorphism onto the cyclic group $\langle x_1\rangle$ which kills all other generators is onto and its kernel is of infinite index, whence free.

The group $\langle a,b,c| c^n=[a,b]\rangle =\langle a,b,c| b^a=c^nb\rangle$ and many other $HNN$-extensions of a free group with cyclic associated subgroups is also free-by-cyclic. It has a homomorphism onto the cyclic group generated by the free letter whose kernel is free. The proof can be found [here.](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0218196709005032)

Comment: Thanks! Do I understand it correctly, that the kernel free group will be of infinite rank?

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it! Here's a better link:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01389176

Comment: [Here](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?GDZPPN002104644) is a link which is not behind a paywall (and is not illegal...).